Javascript, partially reordering array
What is the best way to partially re-order an array?
I have created a very basic example;
Basically I want to reorder the array (before) using the (indexes) stored in the array.
Using the code I have outputs: 14,21,10,13.
However I would like to then keep the remainder of the array that isn't included added to the new after array in the order they originally appear.
This would leave the after array populated as the following: 14,21,10,13 23,8,15
const before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
const indexes = [2,1,4,0];

const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => order.map((index) => arr[index]);

const after = reorderByIndexes(before, indexes);

console.log(after.join());
// 14,21,10,13 23,8,15

I know on a simplistic example like this I could use a loop to iterate over them but the final version is set to be a lot larger.

Where does 13 come from? It's not in before.

What should be done with the element at index 3? Does it just go after the ordered items?

if you are interested in an efficient solution you could check my answer

I'm assuming there is a typo in your question, and the expected output is 14,21,10,23,12,8,15
Order the indices of arr by either the position of the index in order, or otherwise by the index itself + order.length.
We add order.length so that something at index 1 in order appears before something not in order that is at index 0 in arr.
Then, map the indices to the elements of arr


const before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
const indexes = [2,1,4,0];

const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => {
  const f = i => {
    let r = order.indexOf(i)
    return r!==-1 ? r : i + order.length
  }
  return arr.map((_,i) => i).sort((i,j) => f(i) - f(j)).map(i => arr[i])
}

const after = reorderByIndexes(before, indexes)

console.log(after.join());



Update: even simpler version, which has about the same performance as Alexander's answer:


const before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
const indexes = [2,1,4,0]

const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => 
  [...order.map(e => arr[e]), ...arr.filter((e,i) => !order.includes(i))]
  
const after = reorderByIndexes(before, indexes)

console.log(after.join());





const before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
const indexes = [2,1,4,0];

const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => 
  [...order.map(e=>arr[e]), ...arr.filter((e,i)=>!order.includes(i))]

const reorderByIndexes2 = (arr, order, r = order.map(e=>arr[e])) =>
  (r.push(...arr.filter((e,i)=>!order.includes(i))), r)

const reorderByIndexes3 = (arr, order) => {
  const r = Array(arr.length);
  const set = new Set(indexes);
  let j = order.length;
  arr.forEach((n, i) => {
    if(i < order.length) r[i] = arr[order[i]];
    if(!set.has(i)) r[j++] = n;
  });
  return r;
}

// @benchmark Andrew Parks 1
reorderByIndexes(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Andrew Parks 2
reorderByIndexes2(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Alexander
reorderByIndexes3(before, indexes);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



` Chrome/123
-------------------------------------------------------
Andrew Parks 2  ■ 1.00x | x10000000 786 787 793 796 810
Andrew Parks 1    1.04x | x10000000 818 841 852 858 863
Alexander         1.09x | x10000000 856 857 865 872 875
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `


You could move the items (in situ).


const
    reorderByIndices = (values, order) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
            let j = order[i];
            if (j <= i) j += i;
            while (i < j) {
                const temp = values[j];
                values[j] = values[j - 1];
                values[j - 1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return values;
    },
    before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15],
    indices = [2, 1, 4, 0],
    after = reorderByIndices(before, indices);

console.log(...after); // 14 21 10 23 12 8 15



An approach with holes (non-mutating).


const
    reorderByIndices = (values, order) => {
        const
            orderLength = order.length,
            valuesLength = values.length,
            taken = {},
            result = Array(valuesLength);

        let i = 0, // target index
            j = 0; // source index

        for (; i < orderLength; i++) {
            let k = order[i];
            taken[k] = true;
            result[i] = values[k];
        }
        for (; i < valuesLength; i++) {
            while (taken[j]) j++;
            result[i] = values[j++];
        }
        return result;
    },
    before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15],
    indices = [2, 1, 4, 0],
    after = reorderByIndices(before, indices);

console.log(...after); // 14 21 10 23 12 8 15




i think the output is wrong, btw it's the slowest solution. not sure about scaling though

@AlexanderNenashev, what is wrong with my result?

the last index is 0 which matches 23 but you have 12 instead

added your solution to the benchmark. i guess time complexity isn't perfect

looks better and the fastest for n < 100 at least i guess but still the slowest with bigger arrays

@AlexanderNenashev, on Microsoft Edge Version 123.0.2420.81 (Offizielles Build) (64-Bit) i score for the first top and all others on second position.

it's an interesting find, i guess we witnessed some optimizations done in V8 since i have brave on chromium 123.0.6312.122. I'll try to show minor browser versions in the result. anyway, i've added results for firefox to have a more complete picture

@AlexanderNenashev, maybe you have another look to the second approach.

yeah, lady, you've nailed it

To make it efficient, just pre-allocate the array and fill its 2 halves. Use Set to filter the remaining values:


const before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
const indexes = [2,1,4,0];

const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => {
    const r = Array(arr.length);
    const set = new Set(indexes);
    let i = -1, j = order.length;
    while(++i < order.length) r[i] = arr[order[i]], set.has(i) || (r[j++] = arr[i]);
    while(++i < r.length) set.has(i) || (r[j++] = arr[i]);
    return r;
}

const after = reorderByIndexes(before, indexes);

console.log(...after);



And a benchmark:
` Chrome/123
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                       n=7        |       n=70        |       n=700       |      n=7000      |     n=70000     
Nina 2             8.39x  x10m 802 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 522 | ■ 1.00x x100k 489 | ■ 1.00x x10k 438 | ■ 1.00x  x1k 879
Alexander          7.24x  x10m 692 |   1.75x   x1m 912 |   1.75x x100k 855 |   4.00x  x1k 175 |   3.11x x100 273
Thomas 2           4.35x  x10m 416 |   3.28x x100k 171 |   5.19x  x10k 254 |  39.27x x100 172 | 192.26x   x1 169
Thomas 1           4.79x  x10m 458 |   3.20x x100k 167 |   5.48x  x10k 268 |  42.01x x100 184 | 192.26x   x1 169
Andrew Parks 1     7.83x  x10m 749 |   3.41x x100k 178 |   5.99x  x10k 293 |  42.01x x100 184 | 194.54x   x1 171
Andrew Parks 2     8.87x  x10m 848 |   3.49x x100k 182 |   6.91x  x10k 338 |  42.69x x100 187 | 199.09x   x1 175
Nina 1           ■ 1.00x x100m 956 |   1.07x   x1m 558 |  13.23x  x10k 647 | 154.79x x100 678 | 780.43x   x1 686
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `

` Firefox/124
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                      n=7        |       n=70        |       n=700       |     n=7000      |      n=70000      
Nina 2             3.84x x10m 688 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 686 | ■ 1.00x x100k 726 | ■ 1.00x x1k  88 |  ■ 1.00x x100   89
Alexander         19.16x  x1m 343 |   2.84x x100k 195 |   2.87x  x10k 208 |   5.52x x1k 486 |    6.26x x100  557
Andrew Parks 2     8.72x  x1m 156 |   4.11x x100k 282 |  19.70x   x1k 143 | 130.68x x10 115 | 1325.84x   x1 1180
Thomas 2           5.36x x10m 959 |   4.10x x100k 281 |  18.46x   x1k 134 | 136.36x x10 120 | 1329.21x   x1 1183
Thomas 1           7.99x  x1m 143 |   4.10x x100k 281 |  19.83x   x1k 144 | 139.77x x10 123 | 1329.21x   x1 1183
Andrew Parks 1    12.23x  x1m 219 |   5.00x x100k 343 |  19.42x   x1k 141 | 135.23x x10 119 | 1333.71x   x1 1187
Nina 1           ■ 1.00x x10m 179 |   2.03x x100k 139 |  17.49x   x1k 127 | 143.18x x10 126 | 1753.93x   x1 1561
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



const $chunks = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000];
const $chunk = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
let offset = 0;
const $chunkIndices = () => {
    const out = [2, 1, 4, 0].map(n => n + offset);
    offset += $chunk.length;
    return out;
};
const $input = [], $inputIndices = [], before = $input, indexes = $inputIndices;

const reorderByIndexesAP1 = (arr, order) => [
    ...order.map(i => arr[i]),
    ...arr.filter((_, i) => !order.includes(i))
];

const reorderByIndexesAP2 = (arr, order, r = order.map(e => arr[e])) =>
    (r.push(...arr.filter((e, i) => !order.includes(i))), r);

const reorderByIndexesAN1 = (arr, order) => {
    const r = Array(arr.length);
    const set = new Set(indexes);
    let i = -1, j = order.length;
    while(++i < order.length) r[i] = arr[order[i]], set.has(i) || (r[j++] = arr[i]);
    while(++i < r.length) set.has(i) || (r[j++] = arr[i]);
    return r;
}

const reorderByIndexesT1 = (arr, order) => {
    const result = [];

    for (const i of order) result.push(arr[i]);
    for (const i of arr.keys()) order.includes(i) || result.push(arr[i]);

    return result;
}

const reorderByIndexesT2 = (arr, order) => {
    const result = Array(arr.length), pivot = order.length;

    for (let i = 0, j = pivot; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (i < pivot) result[i] = arr[order[i]];
        if (!order.includes(i)) result[j++] = arr[i];
    }

    return result;
}

const reorderByIndicesNS1 = (values, order) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        let j = order[i];
        if (j <= i) j += i;
        while (i < j) {
            const temp = values[j];
            values[j] = values[j - 1];
            values[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return values;
};

const reorderByIndicesNS2 = (values, order) => {
    const
        orderLength = order.length,
        valuesLength = values.length,
        taken = {},
        result = Array(valuesLength);

    let i = 0, // target index
        j = 0; // source index

    for (; i < orderLength; i++) {
        let k = order[i];
        taken[k] = true;
        result[i] = values[k];
    }
    for (; i < valuesLength; i++) {
        while (taken[j]) j++;
        result[i] = values[j++];
    }
    return result;
};

// @benchmark Andrew Parks 1
reorderByIndexesAP1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Andrew Parks 2
reorderByIndexesAP2(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Alexander
reorderByIndexesAN1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Thomas 1
reorderByIndexesT1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Thomas 2
reorderByIndexesT2(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Nina 1
reorderByIndicesNS1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Nina 2
reorderByIndicesNS2(before, indexes);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




I just added an updated version to my answer. I wasn't writing it with the goal of it performing as well as your code, but looks like it does...

@AndrewParks i've added support for multiple inputs of different length, you can see the result in my answer, unfortunately Array::includes() is fast only for small arrays.

OK, let's go into the realm of micro-optimizations:


const before = [23, 21, 14, 12, 10, 8, 15]
const indexes = [6, 5, 1, 4];

const reorderByIndexesAP1 = (arr, order) => [
  ...order.map(i => arr[i]), 
  ...arr.filter((_, i) => !order.includes(i))
];

const reorderByIndexesAP2 = (arr, order, r = order.map(e => arr[e])) =>
  (r.push(...arr.filter((e, i) => !order.includes(i))), r);

const reorderByIndexesAN1 = (arr, order) => {
  const r = Array(arr.length);
  const set = new Set(indexes);
  let j = order.length;
  arr.forEach((n, i) => {
    if (i < order.length) r[i] = arr[order[i]];
    if (!set.has(i)) r[j++] = n;
  });
  return r;
}

const reorderByIndexesT1 = (arr, order) => {
  const result = [];

  for (const i of order) result.push(arr[i]);
  for (const i of arr.keys()) order.includes(i) || result.push(arr[i]);

  return result;
}

const reorderByIndexesT2 = (arr, order) => {
  const result = Array(arr.length), pivot = order.length;

  for (let i = 0, j = pivot; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (i < pivot) result[i] = arr[order[i]];
    if (!order.includes(i)) result[j++] = arr[i];
  }

  return result;
}

// @benchmark Andrew Parks 1
reorderByIndexesAP1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Andrew Parks 2
reorderByIndexesAP2(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Alexander
reorderByIndexesAN1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Thomas 1
reorderByIndexesT1(before, indexes);

// @benchmark Thomas 2
reorderByIndexesT2(before, indexes);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



and yet, my favorite is the slowest code here
// from Andrew Parks:
const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => [
  ...order.map(i => arr[i]), 
  ...arr.filter((_, i) => !order.includes(i))
];

It's short and simple. Easy to grasp and compact, nothing to wrap it's head around and fast enough.
Yes, you can make it faster by pre-allocating your array, writing a simple loop and doing some clever indexing, but unless this code is on a hot path I'd go with the simple one.

you forgot my benchmark (inserted Andrew's instead), i've fixed. i've added support for multiple inputs of different length, you can see the result in my answer, unfortunately Array::includes() is fast only for small arrays.

Very nice. I wonder whether it's the forEach that slows down Alexander's code slightly. Hopefully, the V8 engine will over time be able to figure out all of these optimizations itself...

@AndrewParks it's rather the creating of a set. but then it wins with bigger arrays...
